# correct braces placement in := within data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here is an example of a problem I am having. Am I misusing or is this a bug?

```
require(data.table)
x <- data.table(a = 1:4)

# this does not work
x[ , {b = a + 3; `:=`(c = b)}]
# Error in `:=`(c = b) : unused argument(s) (c = b)

# this works fine
x[ ,`:=`(c = a + 3)]
```

Comment: Hard for me to tell how it works, but I think what you are after is: `x[,":="(c={b <- a+3; b})]`. (My double quotes should read backticks.)

Comment: Also note that data.table doesn't even like `x[,{`:=`(c=b)}]` or `x[,{c:=b}]`.  Personally I wouldn't consider that a bug, and would just make the simple adjustment to speak to `data.table` in the way that it apparently wants me to ;). In this case, that means any `:=` statement should be the only statement in `j`.

Comment: perhaps we can change the title of the question, since we agree it is not a bug

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: sure, i'd be happy to. it would be great if you could explain why your answer works though.

Comment: @Alex, please see comments below answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

not a bug,
it's just that the ordering of the braces should be different:

That is, use the braces to wrap only the `RHS` argument in  `` `:=`(LHS, RHS) ``

Example:

```
# sample data
x <- data.table(a = 1:4)

# instead of: 
x[ , {b = a + 3; `:=`(c, b)}]   # <~~ Notice braces are wrapping LHS AND RHS

# use this: 
x[ , `:=`(c,  {b = a + 3; b})]  # <~~ Braces wrapping only RHS

x
#    a c
# 1: 1 4
# 2: 2 5
# 3: 3 6
# 4: 4 7
```

---

### However, more succinctly and naturally:

you are probably looking for this:

```
 x[ , c := {b = a + 3; b}]
```

#### Update from Matthew

Exactly. Using `:=` in other incorrect ways gives this (long) error :

```
x := 1
# Error: := is defined for use in j only, and (currently) only once; i.e.,
# DT[i,col:=1L] and DT[,newcol:=sum(colB),by=colA] are ok, but not
# DT[i,col]:=1L, not DT[i]$col:=1L and not DT[,{newcol1:=1L;newcol2:=2L}].
# Please see help(":="). Check is.data.table(DT) is TRUE.
```

but not in the case that the question showed, giving just :

```
x[ , {b = a + 3; `:=`(c = b)}]
# Error in `:=`(c = b) : unused argument(s) (c = b)
```

I've just changed this in v1.8.9. Both these incorrect ways of using `:=` now give a more succinct error :

```
x[ , {b = a + 3; `:=`(c = b)}]
# Error in `:=`(c = b) : 
#   := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j only, in particular ways. See 
#   help(":="). Check is.data.table(DT) is TRUE.
```

and we'll embellish `?":="`. Thanks @Alex for highlighting!

Comment: could you explain why the original version doesn't work? the answer you provided is already provided in the comments earlier

Comment: @Alex, sure:  Currently, the only thing that can be to the LEFT of the `:=` operator is the LHS argument.  `b=a+3` is not part of the LHS, but rather the RHS.  When you throw the brace around the LHS, you essentially send mix signals to the parser.  That is, when it encounters the `:=` it reads it as a "second" assignment operation, which is not allowed.  (ie, if you were assigning two arguments you would use  `x[, c("d", "e") := list(a+3, b*7)]` for example).  HTH

Comment: +1 Exactly. `:=` has to be used in particular ways. It's to do with the way it's implemented internally in C. But there's an improvement to the error message that could be made. Will add edit.